# Do pro emacs users use ecb and/or cedet when building web applications with lots of directories?

Tags: web-applications, emacs, emacs23, cedet

Just wondering, as dired seems tedious.

Comment: Tedious for doing what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dealing with lots of directories, I use `find-dired` instead of just plain `dired`.  I filter the types of files I'm interested in with `-name` and `-prune` out build directories until I've got a single dired buffer with my whole project.  Pressing <kbd>g</kbd> in a find-dired buffer will refresh the buffer with the same find command, so once you've got the find parameters right it's quite convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The Emacs Way is to keep most of your files open, and then use something efficient like `ido` to switch between them. To restore open files across restarts of Emacs, use `desktop.el`, which is almost certainly bundled with your Emacs. I find this workflow extremely efficient.

To find and open other files, using `ido`'s version of `find-file` is extremely fast, so I typically use that and reserve `dired` for other situations, e.g. opening a large directory and marking files containing a particular pattern (`% g`).

Answer (score 0):

[Try using IDO](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings), both for finding files (`C-x C-f`) and switching buffers (`C-x b`), and working with multiple files becomes a bit easier. I also like `uniquify` a lot, it makes it easier to keep similar files apart when changing buffers.

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'post-forward
      uniquify-separator ":")
```

And some settings for ido mode:

```
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t
      ido-everywhere t
      ido-show-dot-for-dired t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not developed web applications.  I keep the TAGS file open for projects I work on.  They are a mix of C, C++ and a bit of Java programs.  I use etags-select with this.  I use ido-mode and ibuffer as well, but they are turned on all the time whether or not I work on a project.  And, I am not a 'pro' Emacs user by any means.